# Positivity of the Fourier transform: prove or disprove that $\operatorname{Re}(\overline{\widehat{u}}(\xi) \widehat{F\circ u}(\xi))\geq0$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, parabolic-pde, heat-equation

Let $F:[0,\infty) \to[0,\infty)$ be increasing, $C^1$ and $L-$Lipschitz with $F(0)=0$.  Let $u\in L^1 (\Bbb R^d)$, $u\geq0$ so that $F\circ u\in L^1 (\Bbb R^d)$

I would like to prove (or disprove) that
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Re}\big(\overline{\widehat{u}}(\xi) \widehat{F\circ u}(\xi)\big)\geq0\qquad\text{for all $\xi\in \Bbb R^d$}
\end{align*}
Note that for $\tilde{u}(x)=u(-x)$,
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Re}\big(\overline{\widehat{u}}(\xi) \widehat{F\circ u}(\xi)\big)= \operatorname{Re}\big( \widehat{\tilde{u}* F\circ u}(\xi)\big)= \widehat{\tilde{u}* F\circ u}(\xi)+ \widehat{F\circ  \tilde{u}* u}(\xi). 
\end{align*}

PS.
This problem is suggested by the decay of generalized porous medium equation $$\partial_t u= \Delta F\circ u.$$
In the Fourier variables we expect the time decay $|\widehat{u(t)}|^2\leq c |\widehat{u(0)}|^2$.
The latter is true if we have $$\partial_t |\widehat{u}(\xi)|^2= -2|\xi|^2\operatorname{Re}\big(\overline{\widehat{u}}(\xi) \widehat{F\circ u}(\xi)\big)\leq 0.$$

My main problem can be resolved if one shows that
$|\widehat{u(t)}|^2\leq c |\widehat{u(0)}|^2,\, c>0$.

Any idea, partial answer or reference it warmly appreciated.

Comment: for f(x)= x it works. This problem is suggested by the decay of generalized porous medium equation $\partial_t u= \Delta F\circ u$ is the Fourier variables we expect the time decay $|\widehat{u(t)}|^2\leq c |\widehat{u(0)}|^2$. The latter is true if we have $\partial_t |\widehat{u}(\xi)|^2= -|\xi|^2\operatorname{Re}\big(\overline{\widehat{u}}(\xi) \widehat{F\circ u}(\xi)\big)\leq 0$

Comment: In the main part you are certainly asking too much. Take $d=1$ and $u(x)=e^{-|x|}$, so $\hat u>0$. Then $F\circ u$ is essentially any even decreasing on $[0,\infty)$ $L^1$-function (in the sense that you can approximate any such function in $L^1$ by a function of your kind with arbitrarily small error). However, among those functions there are plenty with sign-changing Fourier transform.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you would have the decay. Note that here, $|\widehat{u(t)}|^2\le c|\widehat{u(0}|^2$ doesn't imply decay, as $c$ may be greater than $1$. It just implies a kind of stability for the Fourier transform